# Calling a subroutine which calls a two-variable function in which one is fixed

Tags: fortran

I have a main program that can assign values to two variables, x and y. I also have a function subprogram defining, for example, f(x,y) = x*y. I also have a function subprogram that returns the value of the integral of a one-variable function given its delimiters.

I do not want the double integration of f(x,y), I want a simple integration in one of the variables, e.g. y, when I have assigned a fixed value to the other, e.g. x.

So, in the main program, x can have the value 5, and then it calls the function "integral(f, 0, 1)" to integrate f(5,y) = 5*x from y = 0 to y = 1, returning the result as a real variable.

I have these options:

a) create another function defining f(z) = 5*z, and use the integral function to calculate the integral. This is not so good, since I might like to assign another value to x, and this would imply the creation of as many new functions as I might need to attribute a new value to x.

b) I can create a module containing the newer function f(z) sharing the x-value with the main program and the integral function so that I can assign any value to x in the main program, which will be automatically recognized by the function f(z), which in turns will be used as external in the integral function.

c) use the old common statement, that works just like the module in option "b".

My question: Is there any other alternative, maybe a better one?

The option "b" is shown below:

```
MODULE module_test
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL :: x
CONTAINS
REAL FUNCTION func(z)
REAL :: z, f
func = f(x,z)
END FUNCTION func
END MODULE module_test
```

```
PROGRAM main
USE module_test
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL :: y, int_value, integral
x = 5.
int_value = integral(func, 0, 1)
PRINT*, int_value
END PROGRAM main
```

```
REAL FUNCTION f(x,y)
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL, INTENT(IN) :: x, y
f = x*y
END FUNCTION f
```

```
REAL FUNCTION integral(fun, a, b)
USE module_test
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL, INTENT(IN) :: a, b
REAL, EXTERNAL :: fun
REAL :: t

=== CODE FOR INTEGRATION OF "FUN" FROM "t = a" TO "t = b" HERE ===

END FUNCTION integral
```

Comment: There is a (bad) alternative: rewrite the integrator to accept functions of two variables (might be interesting if this case arises often in your computations). But IMO the best solution is b). It's clearly better than the obsolete c) which it's supposed to replace, and a) is not sensible. It's also better than the alternate integrator, because the integrand may depend on other parameters, and you don't have do decide in advance (and it's better to deal with this outside the integrator).